# Create a function from a data set when there is one independent variable and 3 dependent

Tags: regression, dataset, functional-data-analysis

I have a data set which consists of 1.Number of users, 2.Cpu usage, 3.Ram Usage, 4.Response time,

The way I understand it Number of users is my independent variable. Is there a way, a method, or a program to help me create a function that expresses Response time in terms of cpu usage, ram usage and number of usage? I believe regression is the way to go but I cannot find any example using Google. Below there is a graph that show all my values
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

UPDATE: Is it better to assume that only response time is dependent and the other 3 independent? If so what method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely try [Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to model `response time` as a linear function of `{Number of users, Cpu usage, Ram Usage}`.

But, first you may want to read-up the Wikipedia article linked above. If your data can fit into a simple Excel spreadsheet - then linear regression can be done from with-in Excel using the `data analysis` pack.

With regards to:

> Is it better to assume that only response time is dependent and the
>   other 3 independent? If so what method should I use?

You should ask yourself - what is the quantity I'm interested in predicting? or understanding how one quantity differs with a change in set of other explanatory quantities.

For ex:
If you are concerned about `response time` and would like to understand how `response time` behaves with respect to `{Number of users, Cpu usage, Ram Usage}` variables then `response time` is indeed your target/dependent variable of interest.

Comment: I have tried excel's data analysis but the output is not validating against the data. Yes I indeed want to understand how response time behaves so thanks for making it clear to me.